# Showing jars in maven dependencies section without doing mvn install in cmd

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have added dependencies in `pom.xml` and immediately the corresponding jars started to show up in maven dependencies section of dynamic web project.

I just want to know that I have not done `mvn install` in cmd so how did they get saved in maven repository.

Another query I have, is that since jars are availble in maven dependencies folder of dynamic wep project, so my project runs successfully or not as depndencies are already satisfied without doing `mvn install`.

Comment: M2E magic. Eclipse is integrated with Maven through the M2Eclipse plugin. All of what you see happening inside Eclipse is this plugin doing its job.

Comment: So I have no need to mvn install  in cmd  ????

Comment: Not necessarily. M2Eclipse comes with a bundled Maven installation that is used. With Eclipse Neon, it is a Maven 3.3.9. Now you won't be able to launch Maven from outside Eclipse without installing it though, so that is why it is still prefered to install an external Maven: running on the command-line can be way simpler than using M2Eclipse.

Comment: You should always have installed Maven on command line, cause there are differences between running a build from inside Eclipse and on command line...and to be honest I always prefer the final check on command line...without things like Eclipse/IntelliJ etc. in between...

Comment: @user3907559 - did the answer posted satisfy your question? If so, please accept the answer, or post an additional comment which clarifies your question; many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you list a `<dependency>` in your project's POM, M2Eclipse (Eclipse's plugin in this case) will trigger Maven to resolve that declared dependency...meaning Maven will check your local repo first for that dependency, and if it's not found there it will pull it down from the next highest repo you have configured (possibly an agency-level repo, or Maven's default public repo on the web).

No `mvn install` is required, as the purpose of that would be to install your current project's packaged artifact into your local repo, rather than install any dependency.

Hope this helps to clarify why an `install` is not used to copy dependencies into your local repo.

Comment: @user3907559 I was wondering if this answered your question? If  so, would you mind accepting the Answer by clicking on the green check-mark? If not, please include additional information as to your question....many thanks!